# Sort Array of Objects by Objects' Property

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, properties

I know there are a lot of questions like this, and I have been reading a lot but I really can't figure it out. I have a user defined object, Team, which has the properties team name (String), batAvg (Double) and slugAvg (Double). I want to arrange, and print the teams in order of descending batAvg, then in order of descending slugAvg. I have an array of all the teams, teamArray (Team[]). What is the best way to go about sorting this array by the teams batting and slugging average. I've tried a bunch of stuff, but none of it seems to work.

Comment: *"I have been reading a lot but I really can't figure it out."*  So what makes you think anything we write will suddenly help you to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Pls check the following code,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class Team {
    private String name;
    private double batAvg;
    private double slugAvg;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getBatAvg() {
        return batAvg;
    }
    public void setBatAvg(double batAvg) {
        this.batAvg = batAvg;
    }
    public double getSlugAvg() {
        return slugAvg;
    }
    public void setSlugAvg(double slugAvg) {
        this.slugAvg = slugAvg;
    }


    public static void  main(String[] argv){
        Team[] teams = new Team[2]; //TODO, for testing..
        Arrays.sort(teams, new TeamComparator());  //This line will sort the array teams
    }
}

class TeamComparator implements Comparator<Team>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Team o1, Team o2) {
        if (o1.getSlugAvg()==o2.getSlugAvg()){
            return 0;
        }
        return o1.getSlugAvg()>o2.getSlugAvg()?-1:1;
    }

}
```